# Storing threads in a hash

Tags: ruby, multithreading, hash

I'm relatively new to Ruby and attempting to store threads so I can refer to them in a hash.  Using an array seems to work fine.  Here's my code:

```
require 'thread'

modules = {}
modules[:thread_1] = Thread.new do 
    puts "this is thread_1"
end


modules.each do |thread|
    thread.join # does not work
end

# modules[:thread_1].join # works
```

I'm assuming there's something simple I'm missing with hashes that I can't seem to find.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` on an hash yields two elements a key and a value. Try this:

```
modules.each do |_key, thread|
  thread.join
end
```

Comment: I could have swore I tried that but I must have had something off.  Thanks!